# Spring Security - API equivalent for 'create-session="never"'

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot

I developed several Java applications with Spring Security using XML based configuration.

This time the application is Spring Boot 1.3.0 based and uses API based configuration instead of XML based configuration.

I could not find the API equivalent of **create-session="never"** (using 'never' or any other value) such as in:

```
<sec:http create-session="never" ...>
    ...
</sec:http>
```

**Is there a way to set this, starting from the next class?**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class MySecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        ...
    }
}
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#sessionManagement--

```
@Override
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

<strike>You can specify this by setting a property inside your application.properties.
You can find the spring boot security properties at the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html).</strike>

```
# ----------------------------------------
# SECURITY PROPERTIES
# ----------------------------------------
# SECURITY (SecurityProperties)
security.basic.authorize-mode=role # Security authorize mode to apply.
security.basic.enabled=true # Enable basic authentication.
security.basic.path=/** # Comma-separated list of paths to secure.
security.basic.realm=Spring # HTTP basic realm name.
security.enable-csrf=false # Enable Cross Site Request Forgery support.
security.filter-order=0 # Security filter chain order.
security.filter-dispatcher-types=ASYNC, FORWARD, INCLUDE, REQUEST # Security filter chain dispatcher types.
security.headers.cache=true # Enable cache control HTTP headers.
security.headers.content-type=true # Enable "X-Content-Type-Options" header.
security.headers.frame=true # Enable "X-Frame-Options" header.
security.headers.hsts= # HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) mode (none, domain, all).
security.headers.xss=true # Enable cross site scripting (XSS) protection.
security.ignored= # Comma-separated list of paths to exclude from the default secured paths.
security.require-ssl=false # Enable secure channel for all requests.
security.sessions=stateless # Session creation policy (always, never, if_required, stateless).
security.user.name=user # Default user name.
security.user.password= # Password for the default user name. A random password is logged on startup by default.
security.user.role=USER # Granted roles for the default user name.
```

Just set `security.sessions` to the value which fits your needs

This is no longer valid. See MariuszS comment for details.

Comment: `security.session` properties was removed in spring 2. (We have reduced SecurityProperties to a minimum...)

Comment: Thanks for the hint